# How do I detect the image area in an ultrasound picture using numpy/openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a dataset of medical ultrasounds in which I'm trying to detect the orientation of the probe (highlighted in red). I've attached sample images below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I attempted several methods which were all unsuccessful and not even close. Short of training a quick neural network, I've run out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated!

**Methods I've tried:**

1 -Using `numpy`, I tried taking two horizontal slices from both the top and bottom of the image to determine the ratio of black to other (white and gray) colors. If the black content is higher in two successive slices, then the peak is oriented towards that side of the image. A sample is shown:

```
blacks = np.sum(dcm1[:, int(0.25*dcm1.shape[1]), :] == 0)
grays = np.sum(dcm1[:, int(0.25*dcm1.shape[1])] > 150)
ratio = blacks/grays
```

2-I attempted to pass the image through adaptive thresholding algorithm and Canny filter to determine the proportion of black to white pixels from the top half and bottom of the image. I thought that the blacker half  correspond to the side of the peak. This method was not accurate either.

[image]

3-I attempted to detect the black triangles in the image. My reasoning was that the peak of the black triangle always points away from the orientation. Unfortunately, I couldn't even get this method to recognize the black triangle.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
i = 0
# list for storing names of shapes
for contour in contours:
    if i == 0:
        i = 1
        continue
    # cv2.approxPloyDP() function to approximate the shape
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(
    contour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)
```

[image]

Comment: those tiny thumbnails are utterly unsuitable to do any processing on. please provide data. that's part of a [mre]. -- DO NOT use Canny. beginners always use it, it never helps, it always harms. -- are you _really_ asking to find the cone/sector of ultrasound data in those pictures? what for? how many different machines do these pictures come from (different styles of annotation, layout, ...)? how are you gonna deal with annotations (text, scales, ...) in the picture?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I can update the thumbnails for you, but the reason I sent them this way was due to formatting issues. And yes, I am really asking for the cone/sector because I'm applying a triangular mask to hide any text. Again this can be easily solved using an off-the-shelf NN for segmentation/classification but I'd rather leave it as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reliably detect orientation using `HoughCircles` to detect the encircled P denoting the probe on the image.

```
    src = dcm2[0] # DICOM Pixel Array
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
    rows = gray.shape[0]
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 8,
                               param1=100, param2=30,
                               minRadius=1, maxRadius=30)

    
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0, :]:
            center = (i[0], i[1])
            cv2.circle(src, center, 1, (0, 100, 100), 3)
            radius = i[2]
            cv2.circle(src, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 3)
    
    
    cv2.imshow("detected circles", src)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```